# Replacing parenthesis and spaces with an underscore without using replace functions (for loop format)

Tags: python, for-loop, replace

How does one replace `()` and `" "` with `"_"` in a for loop using Python? I understand the basics of a for loop. Like, `i` represents each element in a string. I do feel a little fuzzy as it gets more complex. But I need help replacing a `()` and spaces `" "` with a `"_"`. My first thought was that I could equal `i` to `()` and spaces by: `i == "()" + " "`. But I don't know how to add a `"_"` to replace the elements without a `replace` function. Thank you for any input.

Comment: You should follow tutorials or take courses before coming with such question that is very easy to search and is most certainly a duplicate. Start with [that](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/string-manipulation-in-python) and if you still don't understand ask a new question and show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
input_string='abcd(123) abc )( 456'
output_string= ''

for x in input_string:
    if(x != '(' and x != ')' and x != ' '):
        output_string += x
    else:
        output_string += '_'

print(f'input_string: {input_string}')
print(f'output_string: {output_string}')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
string = "This is an (example)"
l = list(string)

for i in range(0,len(l)):
    if l[i] in ['(',')',' ']:
        l[i] = '_'

string = "".join(l)
```

will return `This_is_an__example_`. However, I don't understand your motivation to do not use the str.replace method.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
new_str = ''
your_str = 'abc()de f g'
for x in your_str:
    if x in ['(',')',' ']:
        new_str+='_'
    else:
        new_str+=x
```